# word won't put diacritics before other character is typed

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007, diacritics

I've got a problem with one of the computers I use (running Win7 Pro x64  with Office 2007). Word won't let me type any diacritics (like <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> = `ą`, <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> = `ę`, etc) before any other character is typed. Surprisingly typing any other combination of <kbd>AltGr</kbd> does work, so i.e. <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> gives the ® symbol etc.

What's more, I'm also unable to put any diacritics once I move cursor to another place in a document, no matter whether the document has been just opened, or just written from the very beginning.

I've tried changing the language settings not only in Office, but also in Windows, but it didn't help. Strange enough, the problem does not occur in any other program, nor in the system itself.

If possible, I'd like to solve this without having to reinstall Office, since I don't have admin rights and the administrator is currently unavailable.

EDIT:

I'm using polish version of Office 2007 with default settings (using polish programmers keybord layout)

And yeah, I mean AltGr, sorry for mistake

Comment: Which version of Word, with which settings, interprets Alt A as ą? Such behavior would be problematic, since Alt key combinations are normally reserved for functions, not characters (AltGr, or “right Alt”, is normal for characters). Is this a Word feature, or does it depend on your keyboard settings (keyboard driver)?

Comment: I have almost the same problem. All Polish diacritics work expect ą. The problem does not only occur in Word 2007 but also in Windows Notpad. I am on Windows 10. And this on 2 different computers, one is running Word 2007 in English the other in Polish.

Comment: @user291737 Wow, nice dig. That was ages ago. FYI I solved that few days later by reinstalling whole Windows (not because of this)/

Comment: I solved my problem in the meantime. I found out that it was due to KeePass (http://keepass.info). 
KeePass uses by default Ctrl+Alt+A as system-wide hot key. This blocks AltGr+a for Polish ą. I set this hot key to None (Tools > Options: Integration: Global auto-type: None) and Polish ą works again.